# How do I make a lollipop plot similar to a geom_bar in R iwth ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a lollipop plot (with *geom_segment* and *geom_point*) similar to a bar plot but my *Y* is *count* instead of a provided variable from dataset and I can't find anywhere how to do this.

My code:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x)) +
  geom_point(stat="count") + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend=x, y=0, yend=..count..))
```

How do I specify correctly the *yend* value? Geom_point alone seems to be working just fine. I believe I don't understand the correct use of *..count..* within ggplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems best to do some calculations before running ggplot. So:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, count)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=count)) + 
  geom_point()
```